# Parlare sul telefono vs parlare al telefono

Tags: prepositions

Given that preposition usage is often idiomatic, are the following expressions equally usual?

- Parlare al telefono
- Parlare sul telefono

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally Italian people say “parlare al telefono”, the other form is not used at all since it seems wrong.

Conversely, talking about the TV you can say:

> L’ho visto **alla** TV

and also

> L’ho visto **in** TV

quite interchangeably.

Moreover you can also say:

> L’ho visto **sulla** TV Svizzera

but in this case you’re specifying where you watched it.